# Qual alternativa eu uso para resolver o problema da função get() não estar funcionando

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, aplicação-web, tkinter, webdesign

```py
from tkinter import *


def executar():
    l1['text'] = t1.get()
    l2['text'] = t2.get()
    l3['text'] = t3.get()


root = Tk()
root.title('App')

t1 = Entry(root)
t2 = Entry(root)
t3 = Entry(root)

l1 = Label(root)
l2 = Label(root)
l3 = Label(root)

b = Button(root, text='EXECUTAR', command='executar')

t1.grid()
t2.grid()
t3.grid()

l1.grid()
l2.grid()
l3.grid()

b.grid()

t1.focus()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu erro aí é que o argumento `command` na criação da função deve ser a própria função. Como você colocou `'executar'`entre aspas, isso é uma string contendo o nome da função.

O tkinter não acha a função desejada a partir do nome. É só mudar essa linha e colocar a função, sem os parenteses (se colocar os parenteses, a função é chamada naquele ponto, e o valor de retorno dela é que seria passado como argumento).

Ou seja, basta mudar essa linha:

```
 b = Button(root, text='EXECUTAR', command='executar')
```

para ficar assim:

```
 b = Button(root, text='EXECUTAR', command=executar)
```

E pronto, seu programa funciona.